# how can I know back ground color of a button?

Tags: android-button

I have "1 to 10" and a "DRAW" i.e total eleven buttons on the screen.
Each of the "1 to 10" button initially will have a gray color. 
When user presses the "DRAW" button a 1 to 10 random number is generated.
The button corresponding to generated random number shall become red.
Next time when user again presses the DRAW button I want to ignore the random number generated  if its corresponding button is already red.
How can I test the color of a button and take decision accordingly.
Please help.
Thanks-arun karkare

Answer (score 0):

How about this for the color:

```
if(button.getColor() == Color.RED) {
// Do something
}
```

Sorry, I don't know how to then igore this from the random number generator.